# How do find the width of a Text Picture in gloss?

Tags: haskell, gloss

In the Haskell Gloss library, one draws text with the Text constructor of the Picture type. But how, then does one find the width (and height) of such a picture?

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://github.com/benl23x5/gloss/blob/885cca8a9854efb49541cb6172226f888924f5fe/gloss-rendering/Graphics/Gloss/Internals/Rendering/Picture.hs#L88-L92)'s how text is rendered in Gloss:

```
        Text str
         -> do
                GL.blend        $= GL.Disabled
                GL.preservingMatrix $ GLUT.renderString GLUT.Roman str
                GL.blend        $= GL.Enabled
```

The important point here is that it calls `renderString`. Looking at [the documentation for `renderString`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/GLUT-2.7.0.15/docs/Graphics-UI-GLUT-Fonts.html#v:renderString), we immediately see two other useful functions: [`stringWidth`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/GLUT-2.7.0.15/docs/Graphics-UI-GLUT-Fonts.html#v:stringWidth) and [`fontHeight`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/GLUT-2.7.0.15/docs/Graphics-UI-GLUT-Fonts.html#v:fontHeight). As such, you can get your width and height like this:

```
import Graphics.UI.GLUT.Fonts

do
    width <- stringWidth Roman str
    height <- fontHeight Roman
```

Comment: Thanks for this. But I think stringWidth gives the width in pixels - how to I convert the result to Float that Gloss uses?

Comment: GLInt returned by stringWidth is just type synonym for [Int32](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/OpenGLRaw-3.3.3.0/docs/Graphics-GL-Types.html#t:GLint). Int32 can be converted to Float using [fromIntegral](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:fromIntegral)